# Is it illegal to enter a hotel floor (corridor) as a non guest?

Tags: legal

is it illegal for anyone to walk into the hotel, take the elevator and go to a certain floor if you are not a guest?
Please post the adequate laws (for the US) if you know any. Thank you.
Also if you ARE a guest are you allowed to used all floors of your hotel?

Comment: A hotel, generally, is private property. The specifics of whether or not you can enter a corridor will likely depend on the policy of the management and applicable local laws.

Answer (score 5):

In general, it is not illegal.  Otherwise hotel workers, pizza delivery people, and many others would be in violation of the law.

If a hotel wants to control access to floors they can take other actions:

- make the elevator dependent on a key card
- post a guard at the elevator lobby

However, it seems if you go to a hotel where President Trump is staying, then you are subject to arrest if for some reason the Secret Service does not like you.

Comment: A hotel is private property and therefore you cannot enter it without permission. The hotel's workers have permission and pizza delivery guys can get it.

Comment: @DJClayworth If the hotel entrance is not barred, then almost everyone has implicit permission to enter.  Hotels can trespass trouble makers and these people can not legally return.  If the entrance is barred, then people must get the hotel's explicit permission to enter.